# Derivation of Transformation for basic theta function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, theta-functions

Given that $\vartheta(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}$, I am trying to finish a derivation that $\vartheta(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\vartheta(1/x)$.

I believe that I am very close.  I have derived that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2 - 2\pi i x\xi} dx = e^{-\pi \xi^2}$, which means that $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is its own Fourier transform.

Using the Poisson Summation Formula, $\sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n)$, I am hoping to conclude the desired transformation.

My complex-analysis text tells me it is supposed to be a simple u-substitution with $u\sqrt{t} = x$.  When I do that then $\sqrt{t} du = dx$ and so $$
\frac{e^{-\pi \xi^2}}{\sqrt{t}} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi tu^2}e^{-2\pi i (\sqrt{t}u)\xi} du
$$
but this doesn't tell me anything useful besides that I do not have the right answer.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t) = e^{-\pi t^2}$. Then $\hat{f}(\xi) = e^{-\pi \xi^2}$. Hence, by Poisson's summation formula,

$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty f(n\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\hat{f}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2/x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\vartheta\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Therefore,

$$\vartheta(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \vartheta\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Comment: Just beat me to it (+1)

Comment: Well, I certainly feel like an idiot. Thanks!